# php data validation inserting image

Tags: php, validation, insert

I'm trying to validate image data type and size in PHP, but I can't work out how to do this. Im validating the text fields so far, but with images I need some guidance. Please may someone assist?

```
    $post_cat        = dataValidation($_POST['cat']);
    $post_keywords   = dataValidation($_POST['post_keywords']);
    $post_author     = dataValidation($_POST['post_author']);


    function dataValidation($cleandata) {
      $data = trim($cleandata);
      $data = stripslashes($cleandata);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($cleandata);
      return $cleandata;
}   


    $post_image =       imageValidate($_FILES['post_image'] ['name']); 
    $post_image_type  = imageValidate($_FILES['post_image'] ['type'])
    $post_image_tmp   = imageValidate($_FILES['post_image'] ['tmp_name']);  
    $post_image_size  = imageValidate($_FILES['post_image'] ['size']); 




    function imageValidate {

       // validate image size and type here 
       }
```

Many thanks 
p

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
$filecheck = basename($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
$ext = strtolower(substr($filecheck, strrpos($filecheck, '.') + 1));

if (!(($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "gif" || $ext == "png") && ($_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/png") && 
    ($_FILES["imagefile"]["size"] < 2120000))){
    echo "F2";
    die();
}
```